# How to start keycloak 2.0 on 8080 port?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, keycloak, undertow

Default port of Keycloak used to be on **8080**. Now when I am starting keycloak using

`./bin/standalone.sh`

then it is getting start on **9990** port. //  So I guess now keycloak default port is 9990 nowadays.

but funny part is whenever I am giving explicit keycloak port like below:

```
 ./bin/standalone.sh  -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=8080
```

after this keycloak is starting on port **17101** . So weird.

I am struggling to start keycloak on **8080** port. How can I do that?

And one more thing :

surprisingly something called as undertow is running on 8080 port. When I am trying to start keycloak, I can trace that in stacktrace:

```
YUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/#before-you-start-2

Comment: What about not being version specific in the question and leave that to the answer instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you run basic `bin/standalone.sh` without changing any configuration, your keycloak server will be started on port `8080`.

I believe what confuses you is the log you get when your server starts, more specifically this part:

> 12:25:25,688 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990

Port `9990` is not your keycloak server, it is WildFly one.

You are also using offset wrong. Basically, offset is the number you increment your original port (`8080`) for.

If you set offset to 15, your keycloak server will run on port `8095`.

Also, before starting keycloak, check if there is any other process using port 8080

```
lsof -i :8080
```

Answer (score 21):

I changed the http port of **keycloak** serve (I'm using `19.0.1` version distribution powered by **Quarkus**) by doing the following steps :

1. Open : `keycloak-folder/conf/keycloak.conf`
2. Set the port number : `http-port=8180`

Note that you can also set the port number at the command line :

**on Linux/Unix:**

```
$ bin/kc.sh start-dev --http-port=8180
```

**on Windows:**

```
$ bin\kc.bat start-dev --http-port=8180
```

Answer (score 16):

The default port is still 8080.  Check in `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` in the Keycloak installation directory and look for `jboss.http.port`.  If you want to force the port, use `-Djboss.http.port=8080`.  You're using the *offset* configuration.  In your case, because `standalone.xml` appears to have been changed you're adding 8080 to the base port.

Comment: surprisingly something called as undertow is running on 8080 port. When I am trying to start keycloak. YUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: - Thanks,  I tried -Djboss.http.port=8080 but still its starting on  9990 port. undertow is listening on 8080

Answer (score 9):

```
 ./bin/standalone.sh  -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=8080
```

By providing value `8080` for `jboss.socket.binding.port-offset`, you add **"8080" to all portbindings** on the server which is **wrong**.

You can do the following to get rid of your problem.

```
./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000
```

This adds "`1000`" to all `portbindings` on the server, which **avoids port conflicts**.

Answer (score 2):

you can also run it by docker instead of installing it. more easy to paste this command in docker-compose file in project and if you want to change port you can do it easly:

```
version: ‘3’
volumes:
  Postgres_data:
      driver: local
services:
   postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
           - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      ports:
           - 5432:5432
      environment:
           POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
           POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
           POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
   keycloak:
       image: jboss/keycloak
       environment:
            DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
            DB_ADDR: postgres
            DB_DATABASE: keycloak
            DB_USER: keycloak
            DB_SCHEMA: public
            DB_PASSWORD: password
            KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
            KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
            # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC             parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn’t be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
            #JDBC_PARAMS: “ssl=true”
       ports:
            - 8080:8080
       depends_on:
            - postgres
```